# Windows 2008 Server RemoteApp. How to keep the app running after disconnected from the server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-services

I have implemented an application which is available through RemoteApp over the internet.
The application is processing large amount of data which in some cases takes even 4-5 days to complete.

At this point an application user has to keep it open all time the application is running to be able to finish the task.

I was wondering if it's possible to close the connection with the RemoteApp server and still keep the application running. In standard Terminal Service scenario I can just click "the cross" button on the Terminal Server Session bar and disconnect without logging off.

In the RemoteApp scenario there is no TS bar on the top of the screen and by clicking X button within the application the server closes the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1**

There is a setting in the Group Policies on the server that controls how RemoteApp applications should behave when they are disconnected.
Basically, a log off is performed by default when you close a RemoteApp, but you can change this setting to up to 5 days (might be possible to increase this limit through the registry).

You will find the settings on the server here (for Win2008):

```
Local group Policies (run gpedit.msc)
  > Computer Configuration
    > Administrative Templates
      > Windows Components
        > Remote Desktop Services
          > Remote Desktop Session Host 
            > Session Time Limits
              > Set time limit for logoff of RemoteApp sessions
```

*Note*: make sure you don't override disconnect/log-off settings through the Computer Configuration or User configuration or it won't have any effect as they would have precedence.

**Solution 2**

Use the [tsdiscon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490805%28v=technet.10%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN) tool to disconnect the session instead of closing the application.
In that case, make sure again that your Computer configuration or user Configuration settings do not enforce some time-out that would result in the session being closed when you don't want to.

**References**

- [Terminal Services RemoteApp™ Session Termination Logic](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119145253/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2007/09/28/terminal-services-remoteapp-session-termination-logic.aspx)
- [HOW TO: Disconnect a Session by Using the TSDISCON Command in Windows 2000 Terminal Services](https://web.archive.org/web/20150107112244/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/321705)
- [How can I disconnect a Terminal Services (TS) RemoteApp session instead of closing the application?](https://www.itprotoday.com/)
- [Terminal Services commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491020%28v=technet.10%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: +1 for `tsdiscon` and the 3rd link mentioning `query session`. But is there any way to reconnect without starting another application? Are multiple remote-app sessions to the same server possible so one can only disconnect from a long running program while another application stays open?