# "Disconnecting" from a RemoteApp

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, terminal-services, remoteapp

I've setup a server with Windows Server 2012 and I have 2 clients (my Laptop and my PC, just to give you the context). I will not demand to access the program twice. I use the server mainly as a file server.

What I want is to be able to safely disconnect from a RemoteApp without closing it and without "restarting" it. I want to be able to "continue" the application just as I can continue a remote desktop connection.

I've read [Windows 2008 Server RemoteApp. How to keep the app running after disconnected from the server](https://superuser.com/questions/220583/windows-2008-server-remoteapp-how-to-keep-the-app-running-after-disconnected-fr) and I think it is a similar question, but for one the Windows version is different and for the other I have already managed to run a remote application by making a few entries in the servers registry and creating the RDP-file (and modify it).

So let's say the program I want to keep "open" even after disconnect is xchat or mirc... imagine I've joined some channels and then decided I want to shutdown my client, but I don't want to shutdown the application. I just disconnect and continue from my Laptop. How would I go about this? At the moment I've got the impression that I "hacked" my way solution (following this: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx)), but even if I disconnect using tsdiscon from the server console, once I reconnect the connection of this program is reset (as if the program is started anew).

My server is not a AD DS server, because I don't think I need a domain at all nor am I saving profiles on my server. How can I make use of RemoteApp properly if possible - or is there perhaps some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are doing all this just to keep an IRC client open, aside from testing RemoteApp, look into setting up a bouncer (ZNC being a good one) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Icon in the system tray to disconnect without closing anything.

You right click on it and choose disconnect from all or the specific session.

[image: System Tray Icon]

You will also need to make sure that the session collections is set to not end a disconnected session.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to to this command line or Powershell ?